# AutoMapper - mapper not found

Tags: .net, automapper

I can't seem to get anything working with AutoMapper...

First off, the documentation is wrong or outdated or I'm stupid:

```
AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure(); // this doesn't exist
```

Second, I'm creating my maps by calling:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(myType1, myType2)
```

where the types are literally exact property maps of one another.

But when I call

```
Mapper.Map(myInstanceOf1, myType2)
```

I get a mapper not found error. And if I check the AutoMapper internal _objectMapperCache Dictionary, I can see the internal value for my mapping above is null (hence the exception).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the generic syntax, it works for me:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>().ForMember(....

b = Mapper.Map<A, B>(a);
```

Comment: Do I need to use ForMember? I just want all properties mapped.

Comment: I use it just in case, but I guess you don't need to. By the way, I never call `Configure()` because I don't have a custom configuration.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the `AutoMapperConfiguration` class yourself. Add a static `Configure` method and put your configuration code there. For example:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
       Mapper.Initialize( x => x.AddProfile<MyProfile>() );
    }
}

public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
       get { return "MyProfile"; }
    }

    public MyProfile()
    {
    // Configuration here
      CreateMap<Account, AccountViewModel>();
    }
}
```